# How to model an OLTP audit table in dimensional schema?

Tags: dimensional-modeling, star-schema

We have an audit table which we get from OLTP system, it records any activity done by the user including if he downloaded some attachment, or read some note or written some note , or any change for an incident etc.How do we include these audit table activity in our dimensional model for incident management system(IT service management)?

Answer (score 1):

On a simple level, which is all I can provide based on the level of detail in the question, is to look at your audit table and decide which categories of audit you want to be a dimension. Perhaps there are audit_type, user_type, and audit_subtype fields or something like that? Also, typically you have another field called a "measure" or "quantity", which is typically used for stats on numerics, to support aggregate functions. For example, you might typically have store_id, product_cat as categorical dimensions, but roll up sales$ as min,max,avg,stdev grouped by different date types like month, quarter and other dimensions. If your data is purely categorical by date, then COUNT() is usually used as a calculated measure.

You really just need to decide how you want to be able to drill up and drill down though the data, which categories matter, and which quantities matter. Once you decide that, create a flat table with FKs to lookup tables. A star schema is simply a fat table with a bunch of lookup tables floating around it like a star.

Hope this helps